# Guest Entries ignores redirect field?

Tags: plugins

I'm looking into a project another developer has done, and after submission of a front-end form the system is ignoring the redirect set in the template. The form is being submitted and saved correctly though.

Anyone got any ideas why this would be?

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="download-subscribe">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/downloads/available-downloads/">
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="11">

    <div class="field name">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" name="fields[firstName]">
    </div>

    ...

</form>
```

Possible complications, which i expect aren't a problem but might be worth knowing:

- The form is in an include rather than in the template directly
- The form is being spat out mid-way through a matrix loop (i.e., if the loop is count 2 then first spit out the form).

Comment: Is the submission happening over an AJAX request maybe? Maybe you've got another plugin installed listening to 'onBeforeSaveEntry` interfering?

Comment: That's the problem, thanks Brad - the other dev had Guest Entries Email Notification and Sprout Invisible Captcha installed - the latter is breaking the redirect.

Comment: Nice... would you mind adding that as an official answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: As Brad guessed; the problem was a plugin, specifically Sprout Invisible Captcha. Disabling that allowed the form redirect to work properly again.

Comment: Did you used an alternative to prevent spam for your form? I found https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.spamguard but it does not look to be very active (last update a year ago)

Comment: We'll look into what might be going on with Invisible Captcha and Guest Entries.

Comment: I had the same issue with 0.8.1, but it's fixed with 0.8.2.